# Service Fabric - Calling a named partition for a stateful service

Tags: c#, azure-service-fabric

I can't seem to figure out how to send a call to a specific named partition using `ServiceProxy` and there doesn't seem to be any documentation specific to this.  This is how you would do it for a `Int64RangePartitionInformation`

```
var partitionInformation = (Int64RangePartitionInformation)selectedPartition.PartitionInformation;
var partitionKey = ServicePartitionKey(partitionInformation.LowKey);    
IListen listenerClient = ServiceProxy.Create<IListen>(uri,partitionKey );
```

But there doesn't seem to be a way to get `ServicePartitionKey` for  `NamedPartitionInformation`.  Do you include the partition name in the `Uri` or something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ServicePartitionKey` has an overload that takes a string.

```
var partitionKey = new ServicePartitionKey("partitionName");
IListen listenerClient = ServiceProxy.Create<IListen>(uri,partitionKey);
```

You shouldn't need to do any more than that.

However, if you don't know the partitions up front and you need to query them:

```
using(var client = new FabricClient())
{
    var partitions = await client.QueryManager.GetPartitionListAsync(serviceName);

    foreach (var partition in partitions)
    {
        var partitionInformation = (NamedPartitionInformation)partition.PartitionInformation;
        var partitionKey = ServicePartitionKey(partitionInformation.Name);    
        IListen listenerClient = ServiceProxy.Create<IListen>(uri,partitionKey);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sigh, it was so simple.